# yeoman generator-gulp-bootstrap not installing properly

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, yeoman, yeoman-generator, node-sass

I will try to give as much information as possible on my problem, however part of the problem is that it prevents me from seeing everything that went wrong.

First of all, when I installed generator-gulp-bootstrap, it gave me a bunch of peer dependency warnings, but yeoman itself appeared to install fine, and they were just warnings, not actual errors.

Then, when i try to start a new bootstrap project in yeoman `yo gulp-bootstrap` it downloads a ridiculous amount of files (88.5mb)-- which is where I became concerned because no npm install has ever taken this long or downloaded this many files. I kept seeing warnings pop up as it was scrolling by, they looked like deprecation warnings, but they flew by too fast to be sure. I figured I would just go back and double check on them when it was finished, but that's when I noticed my biggest problem -- it doesn't let me scroll up very far. It doesn't even scroll past the top of the file structure map that it shows when a package is done installing. So from there I went to the npm-debug.log to try and find what went wrong, but I noticed it's 12,363 lines long -- and I have no idea where to look, and I don't know if I can even post that many characters in a post here.

I only really have 1 thing to go off - the one visible error at the bottom of the install, it won't let me scroll up far enough in my terminal to see what else went wrong, and I have no idea where to look in the debug log. I don't think I should post the debug log here because its 12.3k lines long....anyone have any idea what I should do from here? Thanks. I have tried removing all yeoman components and completely reinstalling yeoman, as well as the generators, and also reinstalled node-sass. Not sure what else to do now.

```
58576 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
58577 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"         "C:\\Users\\Elliot\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"         "install"
58578 error node v4.1.1
58579 error npm  v3.3.5
58580 error code ELIFECYCLE
58581 error node-sass@0.9.6 install: `node build.js`
58581 error Exit status 1
58582 error Failed at the node-sass@0.9.6 install script 'node build.js'.
58582 error This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
58582 error not with npm itself.
58582 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
58582 error     node build.js
58582 error You can get their info via:
58582 error     npm owner ls node-sass
58582 error There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open a bug report:

> Failed at the node-sass@0.9.6 install script 'node build.js'.
>   This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package

It might be that you don't have a compatible C compiler on your machine, or maybe the node-sass build is broken for windows.

In the meantime, just try the usual debugging npm installation issue:

1. At this point I'd make sure npm and node are on the latest version.
2. Then I'd try to only run `npm install node-sass`.